# iframe on error go to other site?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, error-handling, web

I have an iframe, but when the you have no internet connection, it should go to 
error.html.

What's wrong with my code ?

```
<script>
function errorsrc() {
    document.getElementById['frame'].src = "error.html";
}
</script>

<iframe id="frame" frameborder="0" src="http://www.google.com/" onerror="errorsrc()" ></iframe>
```

Thanks.

Comment: The onerror event will not fire even if the url failed to load. See similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646079/how-to-check-if-iframe-fails-to-load-jquery

Comment: when there is no internet connection, how can you go to error.html?

Comment: @KhanhTo error.html is offline..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fragile [`navigator.onLine`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.navigator.onLine) to detect any on-/offline state:

```
var isOnline = getOnlineStage(); // true/false. Is null if property is not supported.
if ( isOnline === false ) {
    // do your offline stuff here...
}

function getOnlineStage() {
    var nav = window.navigator,
        hasOwn = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;

    return hasOwn.call(nav, 'onLine') ? nav.onLine : null;
}
```