# Firing scripts after advertisements are loaded

Tags: callback, adsense, ads

Is there a way, callback, hack to fire a script/JS function after Google has rendered its ads on your page?

I could simply use a timeOut function, but I'd rather not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my idea (not tested):

Google creates a set of iframes in which it loads the ad's content. You can find them with a selector (they have an id that is something like: google_ads_frame_BLABLAH). Use the Browser DOM inspector to get the real ID. After finding them, you can add an "onload" listener to know when it's completely loaded.

An example in jquery / pseudocode:

```
$("iframe").each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr("id").match("/google_ads_frame.*/") !== null)
    {
        $(this).load(function () {
            alert("Ad is ready");
        });
    }
});
```

You can take count of ads' number that are loaded.

Watch out that if the iframe will internally redirect to another page, the load listener will fire twice.

Comment: Almost there. The IDs are something like this `google_ads_frame1`.

Comment: Not tested, but I'm hinting that you should change your `match()` function a bit. :)

Comment: How will this behave when ads are *not* loaded (Google server down, or adblock)?

Comment: In the case of adblock i think that the iframe will not be created (and the selector selects nothing at all). In case of google server down or connection problems... Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646079/how-to-check-if-iframe-fails-to-load-jquery

Comment: Lol... this reads like Bram is interviewing ProGM... just the way you keep leading him/her to new realizations about the solution.

Comment: @NickSharp Haha, just trying to come to the best solution possible. Nothing wrong with some teamwork!

Comment: @BramVanroy oh I know... it just read out like the way you handle technical interviews... "oh... but what if I send it a null" :D